# How in LibGDX paused Timer delaySeconds

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I make this code

```
Timer.schedule(new Task(){
        @Override
        public void run() {             
            flyAway();
        }
}, 12);
```

and when my game paused i do this in draw method (Actor)

```
Timer.instance().stop();
```

On resume game i do this:

```
Timer.instance().start();
```

It work, but when i pause on 2 sec and resume after 35 sec, function flyAway() executed immediately,  not counting the remaining 10 seconds.

How i can paused delaySeconds.  Thanks.

Sorry for my bad English.

FlyAvay code

```
//Муха улетает
public void flyAway(){
    flyAway = 1;

    targetFlyX = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2;
    targetFlyY = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() + 300;
    this.setColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.2f);
    this.addAction(sequence(moveTo(targetFlyX, targetFlyY, flySpeed), desctroyFlyAction));      
}

Action desctroyFlyAction = new Action(){
    public boolean act( float delta ) {
        removeFly();
        return true;
    }
};

public void removeFly(){
    rectBounds.set(1, 1, 0, 0);
    this.remove();
}
```

Comment: Share your flyAway() code with us.

Comment: Code looks fine to me.  Try printing the task's `getExecuteTimeMillis()` (see https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Timer.java#L192) when you `stop()` and `start()` (It should show milliseconds before task will run.)

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem and I know this is late but maybe it'll help someone else. The problem is that when a `Timer` is created, it is given a time on the system's clock to execute rather than a specified amount of time until it executes. So when you call `Timer.stop` in your `pause` method, wait 35 seconds, then call `Timer.start` in the `resume` method, the time that task was supposed to be completed had already passed so it was executed right away.

My solution was just to save the current system's time on `pause`, then subtract it from the current time on `resume`, and add the difference as a delay to the `Timer` using `Timer.delay()` before calling `Timer.start()` again.

```
public void pause() {
    timerDelay = TimeUtils.nanosToMillis(TimeUtils.nanoTime());
    Timer.stop();
}

public void resume() {
    Timer.delay(TimeUtils.nanosToMillis(TimeUtils.nanoTime()) - timerDelay);
    Timer.start();
}
```

Comment: I had this exact issue and your suggestion (calling timer.delay) worked like a charm, thanks @KnowNothing!

Comment: I believe now, as of libgdx 1.9.8 its Timer.instance().delay(long) in use